# How can anyone run access Selenium test scripts without having to install/run it locally?

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, virtual-machine, selenium-grid

I am looking for ways to set up like a central 'hub' for Selenium in my work, allowing anyone to access in within the company. For example, Tester A writes test scripts, the Person B can run without having to manually copy over the test scripts to their local workstation)

So far, I've only thought of installing Selenium in a VM which will then execute as per normal. But if I run Selenium Grid, it will run VMs within VM (?). My only concern with VMs is that it'd run slowly.

If anyone can think of a better solution or recommendation please do give me some advice. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea. You can create an infrastructure combining Jenkins/Selenium/Amazon.

The following is my solution from another post.

You can do it with a grid.

First of all you need to create a Selenium hub with an EC2 ubuntu 14.04 AMI without UI and link it as a jenkins slave to your Jenkins master. Or as directly a master. What you want. Only command line. Download Selenium Server standalone. (be careful on downloading the version. If you Download the Selenium3Beta, things could change). Here you can configure the HUB. You can also add the Selenium Hub as a service and configure to run automatically at server start. its important that you open the Selenium default port (or the one that you configured) so the nodes can connect to it. You can do that on the Amazon EC2 console when you have created your instance. You just need to add a security group with an inbound rule for TCP in the port you want for the IPs you want.

Then, you can create a Windows server 2012 instance server (for example, that's what I did), and do the same process. Download the same version for Selenium and the chromedriver (there is no need to download any firefoxdriver for Selenium versions before Selenium3). Generate a txt file and prepare the Selenium command to link to the HUB as a NODE. And convert it to *.bat in order to execute it. If you want to run the bat at start you can create a service with the task scheduler or use NSSM (https://nssm.cc/). Don't forget to add the rules to the security groups for this machine too!

Next, create the Jenkins server. You can use the Selenium Hub as the Jenkins master or as a slave.

Last step is configuring a job to be run in the Jenkins-Selenium machine. This job needs to be linked to your code repository (git, mercurial...) Using the parametrized build plugion for jenkins you can tell that job to pull the revision you want (where every developer can pull the revision with the new changes and new tests) and run the Selenium tests in that build with the current breanch/revision and against one unique selenium. You can use ANT or Maven to run the Selenium tests in Jenkins.

May be it's complicated to understand because there are so many concepts here but it's robust and it works fine!

If you have doubts, tell me!

Answer (score 0):

If Internet Explorer is not one of the browsers on which you must run your automation tests, I would recommend that you consider docker selenium.

Selenium is providing pre-configured docker images for both Selenium Hub and Node ( refer [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium) for more information ). For making use of docker selenium all you need to do is find a machine (preferably unix machine), install docker on it by following instructions detailed [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/) and then start the hub and node by starting off those containers. In the case of docker you can literally transform a VM (or) a physical machine into a VM farm and yet not have to worry about slowness etc., because I believe docker is optimised for these and it runs your VM as a process.

Resorting to using Amazon cloud for running your selenium nodes is all fine, but if you have corporate policies that prevent in-coming traffic from the internet into your intranet region, then I am not sure how far Amazon cloud would be useful.

Also remember that Jenkins is not something that is absolutely required but is more of a good to have part in the setup because it would let anyone run their tests from a web UI. This will however require that all your tests are checked-in and made available in a central version control system in your organization.

PS : The reason why called out Internet Explorer as an exception is because IE runs only on windows and there are no docker images (yet) for windows. All the docker images are UNIX based images.